# What C preprocessor macros have already been defined in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

In `gcc`, how can I check what **C** preprocessor definitions are in place during the compilation of a C program, in particular what standard or platform-specific macro definitions are defined?

Comment: In gcc, do `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null`. There is a similar switch for MSVC but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Predefined macros depend on the standard and the way the compiler implements it.

For GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html

For Microsoft Visual Studio 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx

This Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Compiler-specific_predefined_macros lists how to dump at some of the predefined macros

Comment: Just to record the answer: gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null

Answer (score 4):

A likely source of the predefined macros for a specific combination of compiler and platform is the [Predef project](http://predef.sourceforge.net/) at Sourceforge. They are attempting to maintain a catalog of all predefined macros in all C and C++ compilers on all platforms. In practice, they have coverage of a fair number of platforms for GCC, and a smattering of other compilers.

They achieved this through a combination of careful reading of documentation, as well as a shell script that figures out what macros are predefined the hard way: it tries them. My understanding is that it actually tries every string it can find in the executable image of the compiler and/or preprocessor to see if it has a predefined meaning.

They will happily add any info they don't have yet to their database.

Answer (score 0):

> A program may define a macro at one
>   point, remove that definition later,
>   and then provide a different
>   definition after that. Thus, at
>   different points in the program, a
>   macro may have different definitions,
>   or have no definition at all.

Comment: Generally true for macros, but the question was about predefined macros

Comment: @CsTamas: are you saying you can't undefine pre-defined macros?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: No, not saying that. But the question was different.

Comment: While your answer is true, there are certain macros that are defined by the compiler, and it would be strange for them to be undefined.